# $f(x) = \begin{cases} {1-e^{-x^2} \over x^2} \mathrm{, \ if\ } x \neq 0\ \\ 1, \mathrm{if\ } x =0\end{cases} $ Prove $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

Tags: real-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I'm studying real-analysis by myself.
In textbook, The exercise problem given as,

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} {1-e^{-x^2} \over x^2} \mathrm{, \ if\ } x \neq 0\ \\ 1, 
\mathrm{if\ } x =0\end{cases} $$

**Exercise** : Prove that $f$ is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$.

My proof idea is

1. Show $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Find Taylor Series of $f(x)$ and show it converges to $f(x)$ on $\mathbb{R}$.
3. By the definition of analytic functions, we have a result. $\Box$

But I think, There are some problems like,
Q1. Hard to show that $f(x)$ is infinitely differentiable at $x=0$.
Q2. Hard to find the Taylor Series of $f(x)$.

Could you give me some hint or another proof idea? Thank you for your helps. :)

Comment: Rather than trying to find formulae for $f^{(n)}(x)$ and then taking the limit as $x \to 0$, start with the Taylor expansion for $e^{-x^2}$ and manipulate that to get the $(1-e^{-x^2})/x^2$.

Comment: you are so smart... thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, $f$ is the quotient of two analytic functions,  and therefore $f$ is analytic there. On the other hand, near $0$ you have$$f(x)=1-\frac{x^2}2+\frac{x^4}{3!}-\cdots$$and therefore $f$ is also analytic near $0$. So, $f$ is analytic.

Actually, the previous power series converges to $f(x)$ for every real $x$, and the analyticity of $f$ also follows from this.

Comment: Thanks you good solution!